# Deducing inheritance relationships in a list of classes

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Given a list of classes, I need to find the inheritance relationships between the classes. For example:

```
class Animal {};
class Dog : public Animal {};
class Bulldog : public Dog {};
class Cat : public Animal {};

using boost::mp11::mp_list;

template<typename... Class>
using class_bases = ...; // a mp_list of mp_list<Derived, Base>, with void meaning no base

static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<
        class_bases<Animal, Dog, Bulldog, Cat>,
        mp_list<
            mp_list<Animal, void>,
            mp_list<Dog, Animal>,
            mp_list<Bulldog, Dog>,
            mp_list<Cat, Animal>
        >
    >);
```

I have a solution that works well for single inheritance hierarchies. It is O(n) and it does not use recursion:

```
template<typename Derived, typename Class>
struct direct_base_impl {
    static Class select(Class*);
};

template<typename Derived>
struct direct_base_impl<Derived, Derived> {
    static void select(...);
};

template<typename Derived, typename... Class>
struct direct_base : direct_base_impl<Derived, Class>... {
    using direct_base_impl<Derived, Class>::select...;
    using type = decltype(select(std::declval<Derived*>()));
};


static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<
        direct_base<Bulldog, Animal, Dog, Bulldog>::type,
        Dog
    >);

template<typename... Class>
using class_bases = mp_list<
    mp_list<
        Class,
        typename direct_base<Class, Class...>::type
    >...
>;
```

Unfortunately this approach won't work in presence of multiple inheritance.

I have coded a solution that uses brute force. It works, except for classes that inherit the same base both directly and indirectly. I don't care about this case, because, in my context (yomm2 open multi-methods library), it doesn't make sense anyway. More annoying, that solution has a O(n^3) worst case "performance", in presence of MI.

Does anybody know of a solution to this problem, or has ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are some additional SFINAE-based gesticulations for dealing with multiple inheritance, in this situations.

Fortunately, you don't need to do them yourself, because [`std::is_base_of` has already done them for you](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of):

> std::is_base_of<A, B>::value is true even if A is a private, protected,
> ***or ambiguous base class*** of B.

Emphasis mine. Simply reimplement your template to use `std::is_base_of` or `std::is_base_of_v` and it'll deal with multiple inheritance on your behalf.

Comment: I use `std::is_base_of` in the MI-compatible solution, which I have not posted. And yes that works. But it is O(n^3). Probably useless for all but very small hierarchies.

Comment: It's unclear to me why `std::is_base_of` would have any different complexity then anything that attempts to reimplement it. Checking where D is derived from B is, by definition O(1). Therefore, any added complexity would, by definition, come from whatever is doing a checking of particular Ds against particular Bs.

Comment: My solution based on `std::is_base_of` (roughly) works by finding all the bases for each class in the list. That's already O(n^2). Then each list of base classes must be purged from the indirect bases. That's another O(n). So, O(n^3).

But maybe I overlooked something. That's why I am asking for ideas.